# finding the mobile model and manufacturer with highest sales

Tags: sql

given two tables
table 1 - sales_info

- salesid
- sales date
- imei
- price
- discount
- net amount
- customerid
- model_name

table 2 -mobile_master

- imei
- manufacturer
- model_no
- price

  pred sol

```
    select manufacurer and model_name
    from sales_info INNER JOIN
         mobile_master
    where sales_info.model_name = mobile_master.model_name and mobile_master.model_name
    where (
    Select count(model_name)
    From Sales_info) as t
    Where t.rank = 1)
```

Find the model name and manufacturer with the highest sales .

Comment: Have you tried writing a query to solve the problem?

Comment: yes i have added the predicted solution bu thats not working

Comment: if we count the model name in sale  so the highest count will be most sold mobile model and with respect to that we can do a inner join and print the manufacturer and model name of highest sales

Comment: 1. Sql server and mysql are two different products. Which one do you use? 2. Getting the record with max value question already has several answers for both products here on SO.

Comment: it's just a general sql query for an interview exam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SELECT mm.model_name, mm.manufacturer, SUM([net amount]) AS Total -- if you need apply discount etc..
FROM sales_info si 
INNER JOIN mobile_master AS mm ON mm.imei = si.imei
GROUP BY mm.model_name, mm.manufacturer
ORDER BY Total DESC
```